# Clickhouse cluster dictionary - having not work

Tags: dictionary, clickhouse, having

there is a cluster of 3 servers. at the moment, a distributed product_log_dist table has been created at the bottom. So, there is a product_dict_full dictionary on every server. The dictionary participates in the query to the table, it works well. But if you add **HAVING** to the query by column, which from the dictionary will be a query error

Query error: Code: 279. DB::Exception: Received from node4:9000. DB::NetException. DB::NetException: All connection tries failed. Log:

Code: 210. DB::NetException: SSL Exception: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER (IP_ADDRESS:9000). (NETWORK_ERROR) (version 23.4.2.11 (official build))
Code: 210. DB::NetException: SSL Exception: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER (IP_ADDRESS:9000). (NETWORK_ERROR) (version 23.4.2.11 (official build))
Code: 210. DB::NetException: SSL Exception: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER (IP_ADDRESS:9000). (NETWORK_ERROR) (version 23.4.2.11 (official build))

: While executing Remote: while executing 'FUNCTION and(and(equals(seller_id, 1233949), equals(is_show, true)) :: 0, and(greaterOrEquals(created_at, '2023-06-03'), lessOrEquals(created_at, '2023-08-01'), equals(dictGet('likestats.product_dict_full', 'is_new', product_id), true)) :: 1) -> and(and(equals(seller_id, 1233949), equals(is_show, true)), and(greaterOrEquals(created_at, '2023-06-03'), lessOrEquals(created_at, '2023-08-01'), equals(dictGet('likestats.product_dict_full', 'is_new', product_id), true))) UInt8 : 11'. (ALL_CONNECTION_TRIES_FAILED) (version 22.10.2.11 (official build))

request example

[image]

[image]

description of tables

```
create table product_dist
(
    id                UInt32,
    name              String,
    updated_at        Date,
    pics              UInt8,
    is_new            Bool,
    comment           UInt16,
    rating            UInt8,
    price             UInt32,
    price_discount    UInt32,
    kind_id           UInt8,
    subject_id        UInt32,
    subject_parent_id UInt32,
    seller_id         Int32,
    brand_id          Int32,
    root              UInt32 default 0
)
    engine = Distributed('cluster', 'loc', 'product_local', id);


create table product_dict_full
(
    id                UInt64,
    name              String,
    pics              UInt8,
    is_new            Bool,
    comment           UInt16,
    rating            UInt8,
    price             UInt32,
    price_discount    UInt32,
    kind_id           UInt8,
    subject_id        UInt32,
    subject_parent_id UInt32,
    seller_id         Int32,
    brand_id          Int32
)
    engine = Dictionary;
```

Comment: what is SOURCE for your dictionary?

`OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER (IP_ADDRESS:9000)`

means you tried to connect to 9000 port over TLS
but usually 9000 port used for non-TLS connection just TCP native protocol